How to use openapi-generator Vertx client code in Quarkus application?
I am trying to understand how to use the openapi-generator generated vertx client code in A Quarkus application that is based on Vertx.  It generates client code like this:
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(vertx, new JsonObject());

AddressGeocodeApi addressGeocodeApi = new AddressGeocodeApiImpl(apiClient);

addressGeocodeApi.addressGeocode("json", fullAddress, API_KEY, new Handler<AsyncResult<AddressGeocodeResponse>>() { @Override public void handle(AsyncResult<AddressGeocodeResponse> event) {

            }
        });

So how to integrate the above in the Quarkus application?
I assumed it would be something like this:
@Inject Vertx vertx;

CompletableFuture<AddressGeocodeResponse> completable = new CompletableFuture<>();

    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(vertx, new JsonObject());
    try {
        final AddressGeocodeApi addressGeocodeApi = new AddressGeocodeApiImpl(apiClient);

        addressGeocodeApi.addressGeocode("json", fullAddress, API_KEY, res -> {
            if (res.failed()) {
                completable.completeExceptionally(res.cause());
            } else {
                completable.complete(res.result());
            }
        });

        // Block until the Vert.x worker thread provides its result.
        return completable.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle exception
    } finally {
        apiClient.getWebClient().close();
    }

But I get this error at runtime:
Access to Context.put(), Context.get() and Context.remove() are forbidden as it can leak data between unrelated processing.
Use Context.putLocal(), Context.getLocal() and Context.removeLocal() instead. Note that these methods can only be used from a
'duplicated' Context, and so may not be available everywhere.
How to resolve?
I tried using a CompletableFuture<> to handle the success/failure.  And I am getting the Vertx instance from Quarkus framework.

By "openapi-generator", do you mean the quarkus-openapi-generator quarkiverse extension (github.com)?

Do you know where the Context.put/get/remove methods are used? If the generator uses these methods, it is clearly wrong. The problem is that these methods write data shared by all the concurrent requests executed from the same event loop. Basically, you can leak sensible data.

Hi! Do you mind clarifying how you generated this code? I have the same question as @Turing85.
It's not clear to me. The quarkus-openapi-generator extension does not use vertx, nor are the templates based on it.
